# Android support version

Tags: android

I am using a guide to implement view pager for multiple screens. However in order to make the page viewer work I had to change inside my libs folder to be andriod-support-v13.jar. this then makes all my other files give this error.

The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

This is the guide i am using
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have an up-to-date version of `android-support-v13.jar` in your `libs/` directory and clean your project. That class is definitely in the current version of that JAR:

[image: android-support-v13 JAR contents]

Comment: What do you mean by clean my project?

also would this be the correct link to get the version 13
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r13.zip

Comment: @user3578388: Such as Project > Clean in Eclipse, or **`gradle clean`** if you are using Gradle at the command line.

Comment: I did the clean and now every place where i did R.id  is giving me an error that i did not get before. It now does not know what R is

Comment: @user3578388: That means that there is a problem in one of your resources or your manifest. If you are using Eclipse, look for red X's over those icons in the Package Explorer, or look in the Errors view for details.

Comment: In Eclipse the only place i have a red x in the package explorer is on the class file where the errors are not in the manifest.

Comment: What i find odd is if i were to delete the v13.jar it works the whole project except for the one constructor for the page viewer.

Comment: This is the error log message that i assume is for the unkown R.id
eclipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Sun Apr 27 11:08:51 EDT 2014
fragment_two_four.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

Comment: @user3578388: No idea, sorry.